# @login_required is losing the current specified language

Tags: python, django

I am using `i18n_patterns` to internationalize my app and it's working except when I click on a link that requires login (a view protected by `@login_required` decorator), I am being redirected to the login form in the default language instead of the currently active one.

How I can preserve the active URL? In other words, When in the French section, I want `@login_required` to redirect me `/fr/login/?next=/fr/clients/` instead of `/en/login/?next=/fr/clients/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not well-versed in i18n for Django, but I don't think this is actually possible because `login_required` binds its `login_url` parameter to the decorated function at the point of decorator application. You're probably better off writing your own decorator; assuming you don't use either of the optional parameters to `login_required`, you can make your own as

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import functools

def login_required(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def _decorated(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return fn(request, *args, **kwargs)

        path = request.get_full_path()
        login_url = reverse('login')
        return redirect_to_login(path, login_url)
```

where reverse('login') gets whatever the name of your login view in your `urls.py` is.

I haven't tested this, but if something comes up I'll try to debug it to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by editing settings.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
```

The function reverse_lazy adds the correct language prefix on the URL !
(with 'login' being the name of your login route)