# Django TestCase Client Returns URL Without Language Prefix

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing

I have the following unit-test for user password change in my Django app.

```
class LoginRequiredPasswordChangeTests(TestCase):
    def test_redirection(self):
        url = reverse('user_accounts:password_change')
        login_url = reverse('user_accounts:login')
        print(url)
        print(login_url)
        response = self.client.get(url)
        print(response)
        self.assertRedirects(response, f'{login_url}?next={url}')
```

Prior to enabling internationalization and switching to `i18n` patterns in the project's `urls.py`, the test succeeded. After that it started failing. At the same time, the actual reset functionality works.

As you can see, I have inserted a few prints into the test. Here is what they produce.

```
/en/user/password/
/en/user/login/
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/user/login/?next=/en/user/password/">
```

The pertinent url patterns for these are

```
# paths for password change
path('password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_change.html', success_url = reverse_lazy('user_accounts:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),
path('password/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_change_done.html'), name='password_change_done'),
```

It appears to me that `test.client` returns a URL without the language prefix. Am I right to think so? Is that expected? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe relevant?: [@login_required is losing the current specified language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821028/login-required-is-losing-the-current-specified-language)